# socket programming , bind() error

Tags: c, sockets, unix

My code which I have written for server implementation is not working.
program cant `bind()` socket address properly and generate error.

## Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    int socket_descriptor;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buffer[512];
    int rval;
    int socket_a;

    if(socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error at creating the socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server.sin_family  = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(5000);

    if(bind(socket_descriptor,(struct sockaddr * )&server,sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error at binding");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

## Error

**Error at binding: Socket operation on non-socket** .

Comment: Use these [codes](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if(socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0) < 0)
```

The less-than operator `<` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the above is equivalent to:

```
if(socket_descriptor = (socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0) < 0))
```

Assuming `socket` succeeds, the file descriptor returned will not be negative, so the comparison will evaluate to 0 (i.e. false) and that value is then assigned to `socket_descriptor`.  And since file descriptor 0 is `stdin`, you get the error about a socket operation on a non-socket.

Adding the proper set of parenthesis will assign the socket to `socket_descriptor`:

```
if ((socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0)) < 0)
```